# How to handle embedded documents in making a graphql schema?

Tags: graphql, mongoose-schema

So far all tutorials I've seen have very simple document structure that is being converted to GraphQL Schema. I wonder how I can convert my mongoose schema to GraphQL.

`_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    booking: {
      bookAny: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
      },
      bookTopMgt: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      bookPerDepartment: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      perDepartmentBooking: [
        {
          departmentId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Department',
          },
        },
      ],
    },`

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the same logic as in Mongoose schema

`let exampleType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: ‘exampleType',
    description: ‘example’,
    fields: {
        _id: {type: GraphQLString},
    bookAny: {type: GraphQLBoolean},
        bookTopMgt: {type: GraphQLBoolean},
    bookPerDepartment: {type: GraphQLBoolean}
    ...
    }
});`

Comment: I see... so you treat those embedded documents on the outside. I am not familiar yet with 'GraphQL ObjectType' but with export default `type User { name: String!}... ` because the tutorial I am following is using that. Did you have any tutorial you followed? Thanks.